# Android Studio import from Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-play

I have a project on eclipse, I just import project to Android Studio, every thing works fine.
But when I upload signed apk to Play store it's say 
"APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs"
I used same keystore, but when I export apk from eclipse it's accepted but from Android studio it's not.
I also tried to change version code & version name without any chance.

Please any advice for that strange issue.

Comment: No strange, you just need to reconfigure signing with Android Studio. One example of how to do it with local passwords https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/

Comment: I follow steps in this link, no difference, Google play still say "APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs"

Comment: There may be some signing differences between AS and Eclipse. Try using jarsigner from command line instead. If that doesn't work, I'd consider contacting support.

Comment: Thanks, this issue just take all my time, but I used these steps to build apk manually http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually  and it's worked, I think you are true it's seems there is differences between AS and Eclipse in signing, or may be I need to reinstall Android studio

Comment: I remember a bug being filled about it during AS alphas, so there's that. Check with google support, really.